# Detect a touch on a subview in a main controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton, view-hierarchy

I have a main view controller class which contains a `UIScrollView` and a number of subviews like cards.

Each card is an object and it is covered with a `UIButton`. I want to detect a tap on the `UIButton` and want to disallow taps on multiple cards at a time.

Comment: Just give a unique tag to each button and on the click you can get what button you clicked

Comment: card cover with UIButton ? what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question partially . See if following helpful :

In your scroll view :

```
 for (int i=0;i<array;i++)
 {
       UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollWidth, 5,50,40)];
       button.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
       UITapGestureRecognizer *rcognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelcted:)];
       [button addGestureRecognizer:rcognizer];
       [scrollView addSubview:button];
       scrollWidth=scrollWidth+80;
  }
```

In buttonSelected method just do following :

```
-(void)buttonSelected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIButton *selectedItem=(UIButton*)recognizer.view;
    //do what you want with button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In all your buttons `setExclusiveTouch` on. As:

```
[button setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

For further Details on it you can refer:

1. [exclusiveTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/exclusiveTouch)
2. [Specifying Custom Touch Event Behavior](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW15)